# Is there a solution to auto-update a .NET Core 2.1 console app project?

Tags: .net-core, console-application, clickonce, .net-core-2.1, squirrel.windows

I have written a .NET Core 2.1 console application in C#. It must work on Windows 7, my clients' systems, so I can't upgrade it to .NET core 3.1 or above.

Now I made some changes in my app and I prefer to write a updater for my clients to notice the changes.

I tried ClickOnce and Squirrel.Windows but both of them are working only on .NET Core 3.1 and above :(

Can anyone help me find a solution for my problem and recommend a step-by-step guide?

Comment: Just go to nuget.org and search for "auto update" - with the results, you'll get a box on the left hand side where you can define what environment/framework you want to have support for - pick .NET Core 2.0/2.1 and possibly .NET Standard - those should still show a fair number of options

Answer (score 0):

I used Squirrel.Windows 1.9.0 and it did work by my .Net Core 2.1